# Nested grouping mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, average, unpivot

I have a table `results` with the following important columns:

- `f_team1` (VARCHAR)
- `f_team2` (VARCHAR)
- `f_player1` (VARCHAR)
- `f_player2` (VARCHAR)
- `f_total_ftg` (INT)

A `team` can be in either `f_team1` or `f_team2` columns

A `player` can be in either `f_player1` or `f_player2` columns

I'm trying to find the AVG of f_total_ftg for each player, and then taking that AVG and applying it per team. So the `team_average` would be the sum of all the individual player averages.

My attempt:

```
SELECT team,
(
        SELECT AVG(player_team_average) AS players_team_average
                 FROM
                 (
                   SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN f_team1='arsenal' OR f_team2='arsenal' THEN f_total_ftg END) AS team_average
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT f_player1 AS player, f_team1, f_team2, f_total_ftg FROM results
                        UNION
                        SELECT f_player2 AS player, f_team1, f_team2, f_total_ftg FROM results
                    ) x GROUP BY player
                 ) x
) AS team_average FROM (
    
    (SELECT f_team1 AS team, f_total_ftg FROM results)
    UNION
    (SELECT f_team2 AS team, f_total_ftg FROM results)
    ) x GROUP BY team
```

Current output:

[image]

As you can see from my code, i've put the team as `arsenal` and this gives the correct overall average for arsenal across different players. How can I do this for every team? I need to sub out the string and apply the average for each team.

How can I do this?

Table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you add more sample data from your tables and add your expected output, thx!

Comment: Does `f_player1` belong to `f_team_1`and `f_player2` belong to `f_team_2`? If so, and if the same player played sometimes for one team and other times for another, do you want the player's overall average to be taken in the calculation for both teams, or do you want to calculate with the team related averages of that player?

Comment: On a side note: An average of an average is something rarely wanted. E.g.: A team consisting of very weak players that you have results for for many years, may have been given some superplayers for a single benefit performance. This wouldn't affect the overall average much, but it would affect the average of the player averages immensely.

Comment: Consider revising your data model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select team, sum(avg_ftg) sum_avg_ftg
from (
    select team, player, avg(f_total_ftg) avg_ftg
    from (
        select f_team1 team, f_player1 player, f_total_ftg from mytable
        union all select f_team2, f_player2, f_total_ftg  from mytable
    ) t
    group by team, player
) t
group by team
```

This unpivots the team/players tuples to rows, then compute the average ftg per player and team, and finally sums he average per team.

In very recent versions of MySQL, this can be more efficiently expressed with a lateral join:

```
select team, sum(avg_ftg) sum_avg_ftg
from (
    select x.team, x.player, avg(t.f_total_ftg) avg_ftg
    from mytable t
    cross join lateral (
        select t.f_team1 team, t.f_player1 player
        union all select t.f_team2, t.f_player2
    ) x
    group by x.team, x.player
) t
group by team
```

Comment: Ah right yes. I think this is the most elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: In your union, you are selecting f_team1 as team.. that won't include f_team2's in the groupings and eventual avg will it though?

Comment: @arsenal88: team2 is there in the other member of the `union`.